# Using Workflow Rule to Move Lead to another Queue after 30 days

Tags: community, workflow, time-dependent-workflow

Can someone help with a workflow rule that moves my leads from queue A to queue B after 30 days?

Thanks,

-Dan

Comment: What is it that you are struggling with? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Create a workflow rule to be evaluated when the record is created and meets subsequent criteria.  Then enter the rule criteria.  Then add the workflow action and time trigger.  You can make the trigger 30 days from the time the rule criteria is met.